# Does the series converge? If so, what's the sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n(-1)^iC(n, i)2^{2^{n - i}} $$
$$ as~n \rightarrow\infty$$ 
Does this series converge? I've tried Lebnitz's test and some other basic tricks, with no success, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to spell it out:
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n(-1)^iC(n, i)2^{2^{n - i}} = 2^{2^{n}} + \sum_{i = 1}^n \cdots \\ 
\geq 2^{2^{n}} - \sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} 2^{2^{n-i}} \\
\geq 2^{2^{n}} - 2^{2^{n-1}} \sum_{i = 1}^n {n \choose i} \\
\geq 2^{2^{n}} - 2^{2^{n-1}} 2^n
$$
But it's easy to see that the last term $ \rightarrow \infty $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: Gorgeous proof!

Answer (score 0):

> No. A necessary condition that lim $a_n$ = $0$ is NOT satisfied.
>
> The series diverges as $a_n$ is oscillating between -2 and 2 as n --> $\infty$. We have lim $a_n$ does NOT even exist, much less equal to $0$.